# Encrypting a value in Hiera/Puppet

Tags: puppet, hiera

I have a question about encrypting a value in Hiera/Puppet that I am hoping that someone would be able to help me with it. The command that I am trying to run is:
 `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/eyaml encrypt -l  'insert key to be encrypted here' -s 'insert value to be encrypted here' --pkcs7-private-key=/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/eyaml/private_key.pkcs7.pem --pkcs7-public-key=/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/eyaml/public_key.pkcs7.pem`
I think the Key should be something like `cloudflare-dns-example@example.com` but I am unsure where I should find the value? Or if the two need to be the other way around?
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated,
Thank you.

I have tried searching for results online to help me with this, but so far been unsuccessful with finding an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this documentation https://github.com/voxpupuli/hiera-eyaml, that's the repo for the Gem that Puppet uses and what I use every time I need to setup eyaml.
You need to create the public/private key pair using `eyaml createkeys` which I presume you've done, and stored them in `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/eyaml/` with permissions that Puppet can access them.
You need to add those paths to the `hiera.yaml` file so Hiera knows where to find them.
Take the string you want to encrypt and encrypt it `eyaml encrypt -s 'hello there'`, I'm pretty sure you need to be in the `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/eyaml/` when you run that or the Hiera Gem won't find the keys. Then put the `ENC[PKCS7,########]` into your Hiera data.

Also, it's really helpful if you can paste the error message.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have worked out that I needed the Cloudflare API token to be able to encrypt with this command. Using the line `letsencrypt::plugin::dns_cloudflare::api_token:` within my secrets/nodes/ example.eyaml file. 
https://certbot-dns-cloudflare.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#credentials